# Set Item checked in listactivity when loaded

Tags: c#, android, list, xamarin.android

In my app I have a list activity and in it you can check multiple items in the list, how can I have the checked items checked the next time the listactivity is opened? I think the way to do it is through using getview but I dont know how to implement that in my class because I am not using a custom listadapter, if someone could show me how that would be great

Below is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Linq;

namespace BoostITAndroid
{
[Activity(Label = "My Activity")]
public class Selector : ListActivity
{

    int[] numlist = new int[45];
    String[] Options;
    int[] OptionsID;
    String item;
    int counter = 0;
    Button save, cancel;
    int vehicleId;
    int category;
    private List<AvailableFeatures> list;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

                 List<Makes> listmakes = VehicleAssetsDB.GetMakes();
            Options = new String[listmakes.Count];
            OptionsID = new int[listmakes.Count];
            Options = listmakes.Select(Makes => Makes.Make).ToArray();
            OptionsID = listmakes.Select(Makes => Makes.ID).ToArray();
            ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, Options);


}
}

}
```

Below is my onclicklistener

```
 protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {

            l.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Multiple;
            Android.Util.SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = l.CheckedItemPositions;

            if (!checkedItems.Get(position))
                {
                    l.SetItemChecked(position, false);
                }

                if (checkedItems.Get(position))
                {
                    l.SetItemChecked(position, true);
                }


    }
```

Comment: You need a custom adapter.... You would set them in the GetView and you would save that information where ever your heart desires in preferences or serialized out to a file . Or written as text to a file thats up to you

Comment: I have created the custom adapter, how do I implement it?

Answer (score 2):

if you want your checkboxes to retain their state, you have to save that somewhere in persistent storage.  Depending on the purpose of the checkbox, you could store the state in SharedPreferences, or you could create a SQLite DB and store the values there.

Either way, you will likely need a custom Adapter to display your list and set the checkbox states depending on the saved state of each.

See here for details = http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: thankyou, but my problem is I dont know where I would set the items to be checked.